# jQuery mouseenter toggle

Tags: jquery

I have three 'tabs' which I am using images for as follows:-

[image]

For each tab there are three images:-

- bookaccount.png (default - orange)
- bookaccount-a.png (active - white)
- bookaccount-h.png (hover - blue)

the same with bookcash.png and bookguest.png.

By default I am wanting the 'Guest' to stay as the active tab and the other tabs in orange which is what I have:

```
<div id="main-online-user">

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changesrc('main-online-frame','http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login-guest.php')"><img alt="One 2 One Guest" id="img-onlinebooking-guest" class="left" src="images/bookguest-a.png" /></a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changesrc('main-online-frame','http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login.php')"><img alt="One 2 One Account" id="img-onlinebooking-acc" class="left" src="images/bookaccount.png" /></a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changesrc('main-online-frame','http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login-guest.php')"><img alt="One 2 One Cash" id="img-onlinebooking-cash" class="left" src="images/bookcash.png" /></a>

</div>
```

For the hover events I am doing it like this at the moment:-

```
    $("#img-onlinebooking-guest").hover(function() { 
         $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest-h.png");
    });

    $("#img-onlinebooking-guest").mouseleave(function() { 
         $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest.png");
    });
```

The problem is that (say Guest is active - white), and I hover over it, when I leave that element it will change the image back to orange (default) when it is still the active tab.

What I want to be able to do is either:-

If the image is an active element, when you hover over it, nothing happens. (this is probably the better option)

or, if the active element is hovered, on mouseout it reverts back to the colour it was before the mouseenter event.

I'm not sure how I can do this so I would appreciate any help!

(I know I can use jQuery tabs, but the client is wanting these images so I don't have a choice)

**EDIT::**

I have added 'active' class to #img-onlinebooking-guest and have changed the jQuery to:-

```
    $("#img-onlinebooking-guest").click(function() { 

         $(this).addClass('active');
         $('#img-onlinebooking-cash, #img-onlinebooking-acc').removeClass('active');
         $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest-a.png");
         $('#img-onlinebooking-acc').attr("src", "images/bookaccount.png");
         $('#img-onlinebooking-cash').attr("src", "images/bookcash.png");

    });

    $("#img-onlinebooking-acc").click(function() { 

         $(this).addClass('active');
         $('#img-onlinebooking-guest, #img-onlinebooking-cash').removeClass('active');
         $(this).attr("src", "images/bookaccount-a.png");
         $('#img-onlinebooking-guest').attr("src", "images/bookguest.png");
         $('#img-onlinebooking-cash').attr("src", "images/bookcash.png");

    });

    $("#img-onlinebooking-cash").click(function() { 
         $(this).addClass('active');
         $('#img-onlinebooking-guest, #img-onlinebooking-acc').removeClass('active');
         $(this).attr("src", "images/bookcash-a.png");
         $('#img-onlinebooking-guest').attr("src", "images/bookguest.png");
         $('#img-onlinebooking-acc').attr("src", "images/bookaccount.png");

    });

    $('#img-onlinebooking-guest:not(.active)').hover(

        function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest-h.png");
        },

        function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest.png");

    });

    $('#img-onlinebooking-acc:not(.active)').hover(

        function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/bookaccount-h.png");
        },

        function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/bookaccount.png");

    });

    $('#img-onlinebooking-cash:not(.active)').hover(

        function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/bookcash-h.png");
        },

        function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/bookcash.png");

    });
```

It seems quite messy but anyway, it is working for the 'Guest' tab where I have added the class 'active' within the HTML, but doesn't work properly for the other tabs. If I click 'Cash' it makes the images active (white) but on mouseout it is still changing the colour back to orange (default) when it should stay white as I have added the class 'active' to this element on click.

Any ideas?

You can see this here; [Link](http://www.marandy.com/one2onev2)

Comment: I'd advise you to use sprites and CSS3.

Comment: You can use jQuery tabs with custom tab graphics.

Comment: let's have a loot to the css pseudoclasses :hover, :active. you can style everything without using js

Comment: can you put this `changesrc()` function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

On click of the image set a class called, lets say `active`

```
$("#img-onlinebooking-guest").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

and then if it not the active link, we can do the hover logic

```
$('#img-onlinebooking-guest:not(.active)').hover(

function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest-h.png");
},

function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest.png");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Will.i.am. I have updated the original question. This works, however, even though I am adding the class 'active' to the clicked element, it is still changing the colour back to orange (default), when it should stay white (active).

Comment: I have added this to the original question (at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to put a new class name to the image like `.active` when clicked.

then you can use this script with `.not() or :not()`:

```
$('[id^="img-onlinebooking"]').not('.active').hover(function() { 
     $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest-h.png");
});

$('[id^="img-onlinebooking"]').not('.active').mouseleave(function() { 
     $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest.png");
});
```

Comment: the only problem with this is that if you hover over the 'Account' tab, it will change the image to the 'Guest' image & the same with the 'Cash' button

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not setting/checking any flag before you change the image of tab in your `hover()` or `mouseleave()` event handlers. You can do it like this

```
$("#img-onlinebooking-guest").hover(function() {
         var pathname = window.location.pathname;
         if(pathname.indexOf("/login-guest.php")<0)
         {
           //guest is not active
           $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest-h.png");
         }
    });

    $("#img-onlinebooking-guest").mouseleave(function() {
         var pathname = window.location.pathname;
         if(pathname.indexOf("/login-guest.php")<0)
         { 
           //guest is not active
           $(this).attr("src", "images/bookguest.png");
         }
    });
```